# Suppose that $A$ is a normal matrix. Prove that one can write: $A = G^4$ for some self-adjoint matrix $G$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $A \in  M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a matrix of order $n \geq  2$. Let
$$
p_A(x) = (x - \lambda_1)\cdots(x - \lambda_n)
$$
be the characteristic polynomial of $A$ such that all $\lambda_i$ are positive real numbers.

(a) Suppose that $A$ is a normal matrix. Prove that one can write:

(ai) $A = G^4$ for some self-adjoint matrix $G$

Well i can at most prove until the point where there exists an unitary matrix $U$ such that $U^{*}AU = D = G^4$ since $D$'s diagonal contain all its eigenvalues and since they are all real and positive we can split them into $\lambda^{1/4}$ and hence we let $G$ equals to the self adjoint diagonal matrix with diagonals to be $\lambda_i^{1/4}$. HOWEVER, i cannot make it until that $A = G^4$ for some self adjoint $G$ which is very annoying. I mean $A$ and $D$ are similar so im sure we can do it, but i just cant seem to find a way!

Pls help!

Comment: It is worth noting that normal matrices are the ones that can be diagonalized by unitary matrices, and self adjoint matrices are the normal matrices with real, non-negative eigenvalues.  As such, the problem can be rephrased as: show that a self-adjoint matrix has a self-adjoint 4th root.  Even without this characterization of normal, if the conclusion of the problem were to be true, i.e., that $A=G^4$ where $G=G^*$, then $A^*=(G^4)*=(G^*)^4=G^4=A$. (Note that in general $(XY)^*=Y^*X^*$,but the reversal of multiplication is irrelevant when our terms are all the same, i.e., when taking powers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you've got $G$ self-adjoint with all positive eigenvalues and

$U^\ast A U = D = G^4; \tag 1$

suppose we let

$G_1 = UGU^\ast; \tag 2$

we note that $G_1$ is self-adjoint:

$G_1^\ast = (UGU^\ast)^\ast = (U^\ast)^\ast G^\ast U^\ast = U G U^\ast = G_1, \tag 3$

since $G^\ast = G$; then

$G_1^4 = (UGU^\ast)^4 = UG^4U^\ast = UDU^\ast = UU^\ast A U U^\ast; \tag 4$

$U$ unitary means that

$UU^\ast = U^\ast U = I, \tag 5$

so that

$G_1^4 = IAI = A. \tag 6$

Comment: Amazing! But that means I’m a bit screwed for my upcoming exam.

Comment: @ilovewt:  sorry to hear that.  How so?  By the way, thanks for the "acceptance".  Cheers!

Comment: My paper is full of questions as such. And more often than so I cannot fully solve it.

Comment: @ilovewt:  All I did in the above really was invert the relationship (1) by remembering that $U^\ast CU = B \Longleftrightarrow UBU^\ast = C$; perhaps if you remember this trick it will help!  Best of Luck!

Comment: haha i know that relationship, just that i cannot continue with the next step, needs some smart maneuver!